# How to install printer drivers for Samsung Printer SL-M2830DW?

Tags: drivers, printer

I do not understand as to how to do this and the website for Ubuntu with [this information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersSamsung) is not helping me. Could anyone please help me learn how to install this driver? I have already downloaded the drivers from Samsung's website but do not know what to do with the folder now. I have tried running the .sh files and nothing occurs.

Comment: Most Samsung printers are automatically supported by cups, ie, there is no need to install anything. Could you please provide us the particular model? Have you actually tried to print something with it?

Comment: What message do you get, when you try to execute install.sh ? Did you download drivers from this location http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SL-M2830DW/XAC ?